# Range object with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I've found a lot of examples using the Range identifier and a variable as the end of the range but not as the first part.

```
Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
```

works for me, as long as I identify what the lastrow variable is.

But! If I want to do something where the start of my range is the last row and the end of my range is five rows below that, how would I write that?

```
Range("B" & lastrow":B" & lastrow + 5)
```

doesn't seem to work, and I've shifted around the quotation marks into every position I could think of.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. You are missing an ampersand after `lastrow`. It should be:

```
Range("B" & lastrow & ":B" & lastrow + 5)
```